# Storage size of 'timespec' isn't known - CMake

Tags: c, cmake, time.h, timespec

I am trying to compile the openSafety-mqtt project (https://github.com/hasiflo/openSafety_mqtt) by hasiflo. After installing all necessary libraries, I am now able to build one of the Safety Nodes (sn1) by using the following command:

> cmake -S openSafety_mqtt/ -B opensafety_toolchain/build/ -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -D CMAKE_TARGET="sn1"

This works since no errors are popping up. When trying to make the program, for which I use the following command:

> make -C opensafety_toolchain/build sn1

It starts building the project but gives a error. This is the error: storage of size "l_clockTime" isn't known. struct timespec l_clocktime.

This obviously has something to do the timespec struct, however I have tried multiple solutions (adding the _POSIX_C_SOURCE in both the command and the code itself), the problem seems not to get away.

At this moment I am pretty much stuck on this. I am out of options and do not know how to build the project without the error since this piece of code is necessary. I am building the project in a VM with debian 12 OS. It should be possible to make it work. Can someone help me out?

Comment: On my system, `struct timespec` is defined in `<sys/time.h>` (which includes `#include <sys/_types/_timespec.h>`, but that's an implementation detail).

Comment: Did you try contacting the author first?

Comment: Per both [the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.1) and [POSIX 7](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/time.h.html) `struct timespec` should be defined by `<time.h>`.  The code at https://github.com/hasiflo/openSafety_mqtt/blob/master/SHNF_Time/Time.c does have `#include <time.h>`.  (It also has several race conditions when updating `i_initialTimerValue`...)  Please provide more details about the error message(s) you are getting.

Comment: Well, actually the error I provided, so: storage of size "l_clockTime" isn't known. struct timespec l_clocktime. Is the only error I get. There is noting else given.

Comment: Please post the exact full verbose error including  whole compilation output from `make VERBOSE=1`

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: And what did you define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to?